# Timing issue with mysql query in NodeJS

Tags: mysql, node.js, asynchronous, timing

I'm using mysql module in nodejs.

I want to do something like this, but the problem is that the callback of query is async and I can't fill the result array correctly.. How can I do? Thanks!

```
function fn(callback) {
    client.query(
        'SELECT * FROM imbarcazioni',
        function select(err, ships) {
        if(err) {
            throw err;
        }

        ships.forEach(function(ship) {
            client.query(
                'SELECT * FROM storico_imbarcazioni WHERE id_imbarcazione=' + ship.id,
                function select(err, hist) {
                    ship.history = hist;
                }
            );
        });

        callback(hist);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As usual, I recommend [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) for these kinds of things. Here, you could use [async.map](https://github.com/caolan/async#map):

```
function selectHistory(ship, callback) {
    client.query('SELECT * FROM storico_imbarcazioni WHERE id_imbarcazione = ?', [ship.id], function(err, history) {
        if(err) return callback(err);
        ship.history = history;
        callback(null, ship);
    });
}

client.query('SELECT * FROM imbarcazoni', function(err, ships) {
    async.map(ships, selectHistory, function(err, ships) {
        // ships is an array with each ship along with it's history
    });
});
```

That said, for your particular example, I would rather use a `JOIN` and handle it in SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM imbarcazioni
LEFT JOIN storico_imbarcazoni ON storico_imbarcazoni.id_imbarcazione = imbarcazioni.id
```

Comment: thanks, it's what I'm looking for! for the left join i tried but without success..

Comment: @frx08: Thanks for the fix! I fixed the SQL statement (for the JOIN) -- there were a few errors. You should [read up on JOINs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)), and [here is a nice visualization](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html) by StackOverflow co-founder Jeff Atwood.

Comment: the problem for the sql way is that I want to have a single ship object that contains the own history object, while with the sql query I get many duplicate objects..

Comment: Yes, you will have to normalize the results to fit your requested model, but the performance win is huge and, well, `JOIN` is basically what relational databases are all about.

Comment: Thanks for your response, Linus.  This helped me with something I was getting hung up on.  Now my code is nice and clean.  And it works.  :)